# Intersection of cuttings with a new hyperplane in d dimensions

Tags: computational-geometry, arrangements

Consider a d dimensional space with $n$ hyperplanes in general position. Based on these hyperplanes $n/r$ *cuttings* are constructed. If a new hyperplane is given, how many of the $d$-simplices from the *cutting* intersect with it? Are there upper and lower bounds studied in such a setting?